# Is there a VS Code shortcut that aligns/idents lines of code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannot find a shortcut that that aligns/idents lines of code in VS Code.

[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4Hg.png)

[what i want the shortcut to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p91Z7.png)

Comment: You don't want all the code on one line. You want the lines aligned with each other, presumably indented according to their tags' level of nesting within the DOM.

Comment: @underscore_d exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can search for *lonefy* on vscode plugins and download it! Whenever you save the file it gets indented just like how you want.